# Separate MacOS Dock positioning on different displays

Tags: macos, display, dock

I've got two displays arranged like so:

[image]

I'd like my dock to appear along the bottom of my primary (horizontal) screen but show on the left of my secondary (vertical) screen.

Is there any way to do this on MacOS?

Comment: Not natively, though someone may know of a 3rd party utility.

Comment: [DragThing](https://dragthing.com/english/about.html) may be something to experiment with. It is shareware so you can give it a look. Pay for a license to unlock other features. Works on Mojave.

Comment: Great picture. Linking to a question with an answer to this.